# Socket.io / ARI error: Emit Alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, socket.io

I am currently trying to add a bit of error handling which shows up in the front end of my web application at the moment, but I don't know how to get socket.io to emit an alert box to the front end so far example, I put in an exetension number to bridge  call, if that call doesnt exist then display alert.

The code should make it seem a bit more clear.

**Client Side**

When button is clicked emit the data found in the input box to the server side

```
$(document).on('click', '.bridge', function () {
    var bridge = $('input').val();
    socket.emit('bridge', bridge);
    console.log(bridge)
});
```

**Server Side**

Store the data received from client side into a var and then call the stasis function.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.on('bridge', function (data) {
  bridgeCall(data);
  console.log("Reached listener for bridge")
});
    });
```

**Stasis function**

Bridge the channel which you have just passed from client to server side using ARI client commands, user will be bridged and will show in stasis application. I am trying to somehow emit an alert to front end web page if there's an error.

```
function bridgeCall(exeten) {
    console.log("Extension being bridged: " + exeten);
    client.channels.originate({
      endpoint : "SIP/" + exeten,
      app : 'bridge-hold'
    },
      function (err, channel) {
      console.log("Channel: " + exeten + " does not exist");
      alert("Channel: " + exeten + " does not exist");
    });

  }
```

I simply am trying to emit an alert if there is an error to the front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to emit an event that the client can listen to and then act upon it.

First on your client have:

```
socket.on("my_error",function(err){alert(err)}
```

Then on the server side, pass the socket on to the bridgeCall function:

```
bridgeCall(data,socket);
```

Then in bridgeCall, do:

```
function bridgeCall(exeten,socket) {
    console.log("Extension being bridged: " + exeten);
    client.channels.originate({
      endpoint : "SIP/" + exeten,
      app : 'bridge-hold'
    },
      function (err, channel) {
          console.log("Channel: " + exeten + " does not exist");
          socket.emit("my_error","Channel: " + exeten + " does not exist");
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

How I ended up getting it working based off the original answer!

First on your client you have to insert the following to receive the event to display the error if there is one:

```
socket.on("error", function (err) {
$("<div title='Error'>" + err + "</div>").dialog({
    modal : true,
    buttons : {
        Ok : function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

});

Then on the server side, pass the socket on to the bridgeCall function:

bridgeCall(data,socket);

Then in bridgeCall, you need to store the error message in a global var and then use it in the error function, ARI/Stasis is weird like that so do the following:

```
  function bridgeCall(exeten) {
    console.log("Extension being bridged: " + exeten);
    client.channels.originate({
      endpoint : "SIP/" + exeten,
      app : 'ARI-Web-App'
    },
      function (err) {
              if (err) {
      console.log("Channel: " + exeten + " does not exist");
      error = ("Channel: " + exeten + " does not exist");
      Error();
      }
    });

  }
```

Error function you call at the end of bridgeCall then looks like this, inserted along with the server side socket logic:

```
 function Error() {
io.sockets.emit("error",error);
```

}